# Filter array of objects by comparing nested object properties

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I recently had a problem whereby I wanted to filter objects in an array by comparing the values of nested properties of each object to see if there were duplicates.

I have tried to explain as clearly as possible the scenario below and the solution I came up with. I wondering if it's possible to improve this solution and if so, how?

Example:

```
let articles = [{dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 123, article: { id: 1}}, {dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 124, article: { id: 2}}, {dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 125, article: { id: 1}}]
```

In this array, you can see each object has a `readId` and an `articleId`. The first and last objects in the array have a different `readId` but a matching `articleId`. We want to return every object in this array **unless** we have already returned an object with the same `articleId`.

Here is my solution:

```
const removeDuplicatesbyArticleId = articles => {
  let articleIdsArray = [];
  let finalArray = [];

  articleResponse.reading.map(element => {
    if (!articleIdsArray.includes(element.article.id)) {
      articleIdsArray.push(element.article.id);
      finalArray.push(element);
    }
  });

  let filteredArticleResponse = articles;
  filteredArticleResponse.reading = finalArray;
  return filteredArticleResponse;
};
```

All I'm doing here is looping through the array, checking if the `articleId` exists in the `articleIdsArray` and if not, pushing this onto `finalArray` and then repeating before returning finalArray at the end of the loop.

This solution feels a little crude, I'd be really grateful if anyone could suggest an alternative(s) solution(s) that is easier to read, better for performance, or both!

I apologise if this is a repeat, from much searching I couldn't find a question and answer that matched my specific case.

Answer (score 2):

> We want to return every object in this array unless we have already returned an object with the same `articleId`.

I would use a `Set` object to keep track of which `articleId` values we've already used and then use `.filter()` to return only the items that pass the test.  Here's a runnable implementation:

```js
let articles = [
  {dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 123, article: { id: 1}}, 
  {dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 124, article: { id: 2}}, 
  {dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 125, article: { id: 1}}
];

function getUniqueArticles(array) {
    let ids = new Set();
    return array.filter(function(item) {
        if (!ids.has(item.article.id)) {
            ids.add(item.article.id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

console.log(getUniqueArticles(articles));
```

---

Note: Your articles array does not look valid as there seems to be a missing comma here in each array element and you probably mean to have quotes around the date to make it into a string:

```
{dateAdded: "31-5-1989", readId: 123, article: { id: 1}}
           ^^^       ^^^           ^^^
```

Comment: thanks this is much cleaner, had seen `Set()` but for some reason didn't look into it more this is really useful thanks. I was writing the array on the fly and forgot the quotes and commas - added in now, thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that removes the duplicates based on the field you want to filter for example

```
 function removeDuplicate(arr){
        let unique_array = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
            return index == self.map(res => res.article.id).indexOf(elem.article.id);
        });
        return unique_array
    }
```